# How to "link" distributed Akka actor systems?

Tags: java, akka, actor, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I see that Akka Actor Systems can be distributed across multiple JVMs that might not even be running on the same piece of hardware. If I understand this correctly, then it seems that you could have a distributed Actor system where 1 group of actors is on `myapp01`, another group is on `myapp02` (say, 2 vSphere VMs running on your local data center), and yet a 3rd group of actors running on AWS. So first, if anything about what I just said isn't true/accurate, please start by correcting me!

If everything I've stated up until this point is more or less accurate, then I'm wondering how to actually "glue" all these distributed actors "groups" (not sure what the right term is: JVM, Actor System, Actor Pool, Actor Cluster, etc.) together such that work can be farmed out to any of them, and a `FizzActor` living on the AWS node can then send a message to a `BuzzActor` living on `myapp02`, etc.

For instance, sticking with the example above (2 vSphere VMs and an AWS machine) how could I deploy an actor group/system/pool/cluster to each of these such that they all know about each other and distribute the work between them?

- My *guess* is that Akka allows you to configure the hosts/ports of all the different "nodes" in the Actor System;
- My next *guess* is that this configuration is limited in the sense that you have to update each node's configuration every time you add/remove/modify another node in the cluster (otherwise how could the Akka nodes "know" about a new one, or "know" that we just shut down the AWS machine?);
- My final *guess* is that thie limitation can be averted by bringing something like Apache ZooKeeper into the mix, and somehow treat each node as a separate peer in the distributed system, then use ZooKeeper to coordinate/connect/link/load balance between all the peers/nodes

Am I on track or way off base?

Comment: You should look into the cluster docs for Akka (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/common/cluster.html, http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/cluster-usage.html).  To answer one of your questions, the cluster can grow and shrink w/o restarting the other nodes in the cluster as the cluster uses gossip to notify nodes about other nodes.

Comment: Thanks @cmbaxter - can you think of any reason ZooKeeper could be used to enhance a distributed Akka cluster?

Comment: I think the intention of the Akka clustering technology was to be self sufficient; not requiring any other technologies to manage the topology of the cluster.  I won't say that you can't use ZooKeeper with an Akka cluster, but using them together was not the intention of the cluster design.

Comment: @cmbaxter I disagree slightly.  ZK is a good solution for the initial service discovery of an Akka cluster, assuming you don't have static network locations.  Somehow your nodes have to discover your seed nodes and ZK (or other service discovery solutions) are necessary you don't know a priori where your seeds are located.

Comment: @Ryan, an akka cluster node needs to know it's seed node(s) which it gets from the cluster config.  Are you suggesting looking up this info first (before starting the actor system) and dynamically incorporating it into the config before starting the actor system?

Comment: @cmbaxter Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  This way you don't even need "seed" nodes, you can just look up any node for the appropriate cluster at start time.  Machines die and move around a lot if you're using something like AWS so not tying yourself to fixed network locations saves a lot of headache.

Comment: @Ryan, wouldn't it just be simpler to use a stable seed node or nodes?  We have a cluster deployed into AWS with 2 seed nodes and we've never run into these issues.  Because we use a VPC we have control over the IPs of our nodes, so the IPs for the seed nodes never changes regardless of things being "moved around".